# How i can to make a procedure for create a form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have this procedure :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   a:TForm2;
begin
    a := TForm2.Create(Self);
    a.Parent := ScrollBox1;
    a.Align := alClient;
    a.Show;
    a.SetFocus;
end;
```

And i change that above code to this, but i receive a error, Why?
I must change this code to?

```
procedure TForm1.MakeAform(aForm:Tform;Cmp:TComponent;Parent1:TWinControl;Align1:TAlign);
var
   a:aForm; // Error Here
begin
    a := aForm.Create(Cmp);
    a.Parent := Parent1;
    a.Align := Align1;
    a.Show;
    a.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     MakeAform(Tform2,Self,Panel1,alClient);
end;
```

Comment: Why the need for a MakeAForm procedure? And why is it part of the TForm1 class?

Comment: You want us to **guess** the error message, right? My guess: **Undeclared identifier: aForm**

Comment: Or maybe the error message is "Identifier redeclared"?

Comment: @Cosmin If you look at the code it will become obvious. The error occurs when OP declares a variable of type `aForm` but `aForm` is an instance rather than a type.

Comment: @David, that's not the point I was trying to make. This is an site for programmers. I expect an user calling our help line to say `but i receive a error`, but I expect an programmer to understand the importance of the error messages. Hint: If you try the user's exact code in Delphi 2010, at the marked line, you get the error message `E2007 Constant or type identifier expected`. If you highlight the error message in the Messages list and hit "F1" you get a help page that actually helps, and gives a good example of a similar error.

Comment: @Cosmin I'm sorry I was being very dim, I should have realised what you were driving at.

Comment: @johnny: because i want to make many forms with this procedure.

Comment: Seems you want them embedded also since you set the parent? If it is important then why not create a form that you inherit all others from? On that base form you then have your MakeAform or EmbedForm that takes a form type as parameter, creates it, embeds it and shows it.

Answer (score 5):

Your original code passes a class (TForm2) to a procedure which receives an instance (aForm). Indeed this instance is not even initialised but that's not actually your problem here.

What you need to do is to receive, in MakeAform, a class rather than an instance.

Your code should be:

```
//note, in Forms.pas the type TFormClass is defined as:
//  TFormClass = class of TForm;
//
//A variable of TFormClass holds a class (rather than an instance)
//and that class must be derived from TForm.

procedure TForm1.MakeAform(
  FormClass: TFormClass; 
  Owner: TComponent;
  Parent: TWinControl;
  Align: TAlign
);
var
  a: TForm;
begin
  a := FormClass.Create(Owner);
  a.Parent := Parent;
  a.Align := Align;
  a.Show;
  a.SetFocus;
end;
```

A couple more points:

1. What is the purpose of a.SetFocus? I wasn't aware that a form could hold the focus.
2. If you don't intend to re-parent this form after constructing it then you may as well do away with the Owner parameter and let the Parent own the form.

Comment: heffernan: 1-the "a.setfocus" is not important. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this is to declare a class procedure in Form2 and then call that prpocedure on Form1. Ej

```
TForm2
    ...
    public 
      class procedure ShowForm;
    end;

class procedure TForm2.ShowForm;
begin
  with TForm2.Create(Application) do begin
    ShowModal;
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

And, in Form1.ButtonClick(...). you just can write:

```
TForm2.ShowForm;
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP apparently wanted, which was to pass a class reference. It also doesn't do any of the parenting.